# Modernizr.flexbox in React app returns 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, modernizr

I trying to use Modernizr for the first time. Following an example and reading the doc but I seem to be missing something as all of my tests are returning 'undefined'.

I'm writing code in a React app created with create-react-app
I used [this tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-quick-look-at-modernizr-30--cms-24932/) as main steps to follow.

All code & config is in the same directory

modernizr-config.json

```
{
  "minify": false,
  "options": [
  "setClasses"
  ],
    "feature-detects": [
    "test/css/flexbox",
    "test/css/flexboxlegacy",
    "test/css/flexboxtweener",
    "test/css/flexwrap"
  ]
}
```

React component code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Modernizr from './modernizr'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let qFlexbox = Modernizr.flexbox ? 'yes' : 'no'
    console.log(Modernizr.flexbox)
    let qFlexboxLegacy = Modernizr.flexboxlegacy ? 'yes' : 'no'
    console.log(Modernizr.flexboxlegacy)
    let qFlexboxTweener = Modernizr.flexboxtweener ? 'yes' : 'no'
    console.log(Modernizr.flexboxtweener)
    let qFlexWrap = Modernizr.flexwrap ? 'yes' : 'no'
    console.log(Modernizr.flexwrap)

    return (
      <div className="App">

        <ul>
          <li>flexbox: {qFlexbox}</li>
          <li>flexboxlegacy: {qFlexboxLegacy}</li>
          <li>flexboxtweener: {qFlexboxTweener}</li>
          <li>flexwrap: {qFlexWrap}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

All the 'if' statements return 'no' and all the console.log statements 'undefined'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't import the modernizr build like that since it is an IIFE. It means every time you import the file it will excuse all the tests. In a context of a SPA you can end-up with lot of classes in the HTML tag as a result of multiple tests execution. In addition to that, the function doesn't return any value but attaches the result to the window object. That's why your tests are returning `undefined`.

To get it working, you need to apply some changes to the modernizr build output to make it work as a ES6 module. You can find a working example here: https://github.com/fcaldera/modernizr-try. Check the [commits](https://github.com/fcaldera/modernizr-try/commit/9c8be94cb25acaa3df19a8f0f0c2923ab40a3866%20commits) to see what are the changes you need to apply.

Although this works, it is not ideal since you would have to do the same in case you recreate the build to add more tests or something, but it is a start and it is not hard to do.